# html5 video secure streaming?

Tags: video, html, video-streaming

Does html5 allow me to do secure streaming video? And by this, I mean token authentication. I want to be able to stream media only to those people who are authorised to view it.

I can do this currently with Flash Media Server hosted by Akamai - they have a custom mechanism where I send them a token as part of the player connection handshake. Does html5 allow for this, and has anyone implemented this with a hosting service such as Akamai?

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean that users have to be logged on and allowed to view a particular piece of content then html5 by itself does not do this.

One way is to have the server check details before serving the video, the easiest being a script (php/etc.) that checks if a user is allowed and then streams the file to the user.

Comment: The "token" for HTML5 videos would be an HTTP cookie.

Comment: You could also just use normal HTTP Authentication via the web server.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Digest is highly secure, and you should want to think about using it anyway over cookies, unless slick UI is really important to you. HTML does not have authentication because that is the role of lower levels, like HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible but it requires integration between your web server and streaming server (or service). I have had influxis add this integration to secure our video streaming for membership required websites. I used JW player in html5 mode so I am not certain about native html5 setup. You also have further issues with mobile in HLS(iPhone) vs RTMPS (android) extra setups.

The security comes from the the media server that recognizes the user (IP+UA) as authenticated (with a token request to your server) to make the stream available or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could save a cookie with the user autorization, and when the browser requests the video, you check if the user has autorization using php.

Just put the video url to a .php page that sends a video mimetype, if the user is not autorized, just send a video explaning it.

Answer (score 0):

I theory: it is possible. But it is a question of the streaming server you use, what options does it have for authentication.

As a fallback solution you can always use a (reverse) proxy server with authentication (Apache is as good as any), and you make your stream accessible only thru your proxy.